# Send object to parent class without using global variable

Tags: java, inheritance

A simple class below to explain my question below:

```
 public class TestA extends TestParent {
    public TestA { 
        //some code here
    }
    public void connect() {
        //some more code here
        File project = otherproject.getProjectFile();
    }
 }
```

I want this `project` file to be available in `TestParent`. Is there a way to do so without creating a global variable in `TestParent`? If there are other ways, please let me know. If not using a global variable in this scenario is a bad idea for any reason, do comment that as well.

Comment: not `public` but `protected`

Comment: create a method and do it like super.mymethod(project), what's the harm in creating a property with visibility as protected?

Comment: What does the `TestParent` class need to do with `project`? If `project` is specific to `TestA`, you most likely want that class to handle it, to keep your parent more generic.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer and @SMA -- Not `protected` but `private`. Protected fields also harm encapsulation.

Comment: @spinyBabbler - In the superclass, you can create a private field, and protected methods to initialize and get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change TestParent class to a abstrac class with an abstract method 'getProjectFile'

```
public abstract class TestParent {

   private void methodThatUseFile(){
    // invoke child implementation
    // in this way parent can use project created in child class
    File project= this.getProjectFile();
     // TODO

   }

  abstract File getProjectFile();

}
```

then implement the abstract method in the child class

```
public class TestA extends TestParent {
    public TestA { 
        //some code here
    }

    @Override
    public File getProjectFile() {
        //some more code here
        File project = otherproject.getProjectFile();
        return project;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was asking for but is probably the best case in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Make it the return value of the `connect()` method:

```
protected File connect() {
    //some more code here
    File project = otherproject.getProjectFile();
    return project;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?

You could create your TestParent thus:

```
public class TestParent {
    protected File project;
}
```

And have:

```
public void connect() {
    //some more code here
    project = otherproject.getProjectFile();
}
```

Or maybe:

```
public class TestParent {
    private File project;

    protected setProject(File project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
}
```

With:

```
public void connect() {
    //some more code here
    setProject(otherproject.getProjectFile());
}
```

Or (!) if TestParent is calling connect() dynamically, you could have connect() return the File:

```
public File connect() {
    //some more code here
    return otherproject.getProjectFile();
}
```